# Alert a web page when a record inserted in the database

Tags: asp-classic, triggers, sql-server-2000

I have a sql server 2000 database that keeps records of telephone calls of a PBX (call center). Every time we have a call in our PBX (incoming or outcoming) then a record is created in the database with the call's details (time, call number). Well I need to notify a classic asp page to popup a message with this telephone number when the specific phone that resides to the pc ringing.
I believe that the only way is to use trigger. When we have an incoming call, therefore a record in the table is added, a trigger somehow must be the kick-off but how? How can I notify the asp page that the user with the ringing phone view?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The only "live" connection these days is web sockets which are supported only in Chrome fully and partially in Firefox. If that's good enough then go ahead and learn about web sockets then you can use them to achieve what you want. Excellent example is this very site which has live update of various details like inbox items and more. You see it updated in real time, and that's the result of web sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SignalR it is designed to help you do what you need.

Basically wraps all the different server to client communication techniques and means you don't have to think about what each client supports.

However using Classic ASP will make your task very hard. Probably easiest to use .Net for at least the notification part of your application